# winforms closing issue, vb.net

Tags: vb.net

i have a vb.net 2.0 winforms application.
When i open another application (like calculator ) have the focus to it and try to close my application the screen freeze and i have to use ctrl + alt + del to get it to refresh.

Any idea what can affect that?

Comment: Can you show the code you use to open the other application?

Comment: There is no code to open the other application : it's just a windows application : Run Calc.. or word or whatever. When my main application loses the focus and i try to close mine without the focus it freezes

Comment: @Jonathan: OK, I misunderstood the question :)

Comment: Hehe :D no worries. i've put a breakpoint on the closing/closed event and they are thrown after the ctrl alt delete .

Comment: Are you handling any Focus events in your application?

Comment: Are you running threads in your winform app? I suspect that there is a deadlock in there as you have to ctrl+alt+del to force the refresh which imho is that there is a thread in there that is blocking the screen refresh...perhaps setting a form property directly from the thread without 'BeginInvoke'....?

Comment: i'm using crownwood dotnetmagic tabcontrol

Comment: Can you post some code for this as we're shooting ourselves in the foot in the dark.... :)

Comment: Ok What is happening is 1 of my control has 

SendKeys.Send("{HOME}")

I've noticed that if i remove it it's working.

Is there anyway to bypass that.

SendingKey if it's not closing or whatever

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your dilemma, somewhere you're sending SENDKEYS, and if you do not have focus and you SENDKEYs the app freezes.

Why not simply add a

if Me.Focus then SendKeys